# Ruby - why this construction return nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, null, string

I have this simple construction:

```
<% if !@user.address.empty? && !@user.zip.empty? %>
   <%= @user.address+', '+@user.zip%>
<% end %>
```

If are `address` and `zip` filled out, it's ok. But if not, on localhost is not printed out the middle line. That's ok as well.

But on Heroku, if `address` and `zip` are not filled out, I get the error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass):
```

How is that possible?
Note: `address` and `zip` have the datatype `varchar(255)`.

**EDIT:** I forgot to add an important note: `@user` is **NEVER** `nil`.

Comment: `@user is NEVER nil` that's ok but there are chances that `@user.address` is `nil` on `heroku` and not on `localhost`

Comment: I've encountered many users who were `nil` and protecting against them was almost impossible. They do the craziest things when there's nothing there ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `present?`

Under the surface `present?` is just `!blank?` which will test for empty strings as well as for `nil`, `{}`  and `[]`.

In your case:

```
<% if @user.address.present? && @user.zip.present? %>
  <%= "#@user.address, #@user.zip" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `empty?` only on `[]`, `{}`, `""`, "    " but not on `nil`.

Use [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/Object.html#M000024) instead:

```
!@user.address.blank? && !@user.zip.blank?
```

To make it affirmative use [`present?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F):

```
@user.address.present? && @user.zip.present?
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be that in  your local database these values are not null but are actual empty strings.  But within Heroku when you retrieve the values without an address you are getting a null value.

If you are using Rails, then you can use `blank?` which checks nil as well.

Just to note `blank?` and `present?` are a part of [active support.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#extensions-to-all-objects)